# Firebase and react native combine two wheres (do a where or)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was wondering if you can do a "where or" in firebase.

In my mind it would look like this: I need data `.where('target', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.email)` or `.where('requested', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.email)`

How can i write a query that combines the two? What would be my best approach

This is what my code looks like now:

```
this.subscriber = firebase.firestore().collection('friends').where('target', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.email).where('accepted', '==', true).onSnapshot(docs =>{
            let friends = [];
            docs.forEach(doc => {
                friends.push(doc.data())
            })
            this.setState({ friends });
            console.log(friends);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do an OR query across multiple fields in Firestore. All conditions you add to a query are ANDed together.

The common workarounds for a use-case such as yours are:

- Add a single array field with all the emails and use an `array-contains` operation on that.
- Perform two separate queries, and merge the results in your application code.

Also see:

- [Get Firestore document with OR query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68439620/get-firestore-document-with-or-query)
- [Search with multi fields firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62441631/search-with-multi-fields-firestore)
- [How to combine "OR" query for different fields in firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63386141/how-to-combine-or-query-for-different-fields-in-firestore)